# How to convert a QuerySet to list in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, type-conversion, django-queryset

How can I convert a QuerySet to a list?

```
myWords = MyGroup.objects.get(name="bla").allkeyword
# To
myWords = ["meltemi", "bla"]

class MyGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    allkeyword = models.ManyToManyField('KeywordTag')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)

class KeywordTag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
myWords = MyGroup.objects.get(name = "bla").allkeyword.values_list('name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Silver Light, it's not working properly because I'm trying to pass this list then into this  myWords = re.compile(r"\b(%s)\b" % "|".join(myWords))  any idea?

Comment: @user391986 - why not? what is the error? On 1.4A I can join a `ValuesListQuerySet` without problems.

Answer (score 0):

[values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) returns a QuerySet's list, then you can convert it to a normal list with [list()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) as shown below:

```py
　　　　　　                                            # ↓ Here ↓　　　　　　　　
myWords = MyGroup.objects.get(name="bla").allkeyword.values_list('name', flat=True)

print(myWords) # <QuerySet ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']>

      # ↓ Here ↓
print(list(myWords)) # ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
```